# iPhone: How to get size of an item in a xib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I made a custom class from `UITableViewCell` as `MealItemDetailCell`.

In its xib, I dragged a `UITableViewCell` and then added items to the cell. When populating the Table that displays the `MealItemDetailCells`, the cells' bottoms are all cut off since they're larger than the table's default height.

I see where I can use `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and set it to something large enough, but I might want to edit the items in the custom cell, and then this height might not be appropriate. Is there any way to programmatically retrieve the height of the `TableViewCell` from the xib file?

In the controller, when I provide a cell for populating the table, I tried `cell.frame.size.height`, but that seemed to return the default cell height of 45. `cell.window.size.height` gave me the whole iPhone window.

My current xib cell is 110 high, seen from the Size Inspector when clicking on the `TableViewCell` when looking at the `MealItemDetailCell.xib`.

I would expect some attribute to be readable so that I can get this.

I searched for a while, but I couldn't find anything close. Any thoughts or guidance? Thanks.

Update (response to Henry Hong below): I see differing values in the Size Inspector. There's the "row height" value under the "Table View Cell" (top) section. Then there's a value in "Height" under the "View" section (under Show "Frame Rectangle"). The "row height" doesn't change when dragging the xib's table cell boundary until I uncheck and recheck the "custom" checkbox. Although, just trying this again, I see both follow the actual cell size when finishing dragging! And now, but not before, using the value incremented up/down arrows, I see the cell outline move as expected. But the "row height" still stays the same. I'm sure this is documented somewhere, but I guess I just have to get the "row height" number matching the actual/final edited xib cell height.

Answer (score 1):

In interface builder click on the tableview and then in the ruler section set the height for the cell to 110 otherwise you get the standard height which is 44.

Hope it helps!
Cheers

Comment: Well, I don't have a .xib for the tableview. I just instantiate a tableviewcontroller programmatically. So, I'm not sure that this would apply.

Answer (score 0):

cell.frame.size.height should be able to retrieve the height of the view from nib file.

Just make sure u have already assigned a value to the "row height" with size inspector in interface builder.

or it will return the default height.

Comment: Responded above (ran out of room here).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can fix your problem implementing the UITableViewDelegate method **tableview:HeightForRowAtIndexPath:**  and return the height for the cell that in your case is 110.

Cheers,
Alessandro

Comment: But that assumes I know the height of the cell. I'd like to be able to graphically edit the cell in its xib and be done with it. I don't want to have to visually get the size from a Size Inspector box, and then type it into the return value for HeightForRowAtIndexPath. That's why I detailed my experience with the boxes and values above.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the provided answers cover your question. As far as I can see, the 'Row Height' in interface builder is just a convenience value, since editing the height directly via number is not allowed – only by dragging.

Interface builder writes this value into the xib data structure as 'rowHeight':

```
<tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="blue" indentationWidth="10" shouldIndentWhileEditing="NO" rowHeight="65" id="3" customClass="PaperInfoCell">
```

However, despite parsing the nib yourself, it doesn't seem to be written in any property of the instance – hence your only solution that removes double bookkeeping is to instantiate the nib and get the row height from the cell's frame.

As a side note, all of that is less of a burden when using iOS8, auto layout, and UITableViewAutomaticDimension.